# How to solve for $x$ in $\sin(x)=i$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, complex-numbers

So I was bored, and decided to do some math for fun. After a while, I came up with this:$$\text{Solve for }x\text{: }\sin(x)=i$$which I thought that I might be able to do.

---

### Here is my attempt at solving $\sin(x)=i$:

---

So how do we even start to solve this equation? Well, we do it by expanding $\sin(x)$:$$\sin(x):=\dfrac12ie^{-ix}-\dfrac12ie^{ix}$$Now, we can solve for $\sin(x)=i$:$$\sin(x)=i$$$$\implies\dfrac12ie^{-ix}-\dfrac12ie^{ix}=i$$$$\implies\dfrac12e^{-ix}-\dfrac12e^{ix}=1$$$$\implies e^{-ix}-e^{ix}=2$$
$$e^{ix}\left(e^{-ix}-e^{ix}\right)=e^{ix}(2)$$$$1-e^{2ix}=2e^{ix}$$$$\implies2e^{ix}+e^{2ix}=1$$$$2e^{ix}+e^{2ix}=1$$$$\implies\dfrac12e^{ix}+1=\dfrac1{2e^{ix}}$$$$\implies e^{ix}+2=\dfrac1{e^{ix}}$$$$e^{2ix}+2e^{ix}-1=0$$$$a^2+2a-1=0$$Now, plugging this into the quadratic formula:$$e^{ix}=\dfrac{-2\pm\sqrt{4+4}}2$$$$e^{ix}=\dfrac{-\require{cancel}\cancel2^1\pm\cancel2^1\sqrt2}{\cancel2^1}$$$$e^{ix}=-1\pm\sqrt2$$However, for some weird reason, I had a feeling that the answer would be found in a hyperbolic trigonometric function (as I have never attempted solving this before), and as such, I decided to cancel out the positive outcome, so$$e^{ix}=-1-\sqrt2$$$$\implies ix=i\pi+2i\pi k+\ln(1+\sqrt2)$$$$\implies x=\pi+2\pi k-i\ln(1+\sqrt2),k\in\mathbb Z$$Or, we could write this as$$\pi+2\pi k-i\operatorname{arcsinh}(1)$$which can also be written as (more as so I don't have to write out `\operatorname{arcsinh}` or any other hyperbolic trigonometric function to the power of $-1$ with `\operatorname`,$$x=\pi+2\pi k-i\sinh^{-1}(1),k\in\mathbb Z$$

---

##### My question

---

Is my solution correct, or what could I do to attain the correct solution/attain it more quickly?

---

###### Mistakes I might have made

---

1. In all honesty, it might have not been a good idea to make the assumptions that I made throughout my finding the solution, but that's just me.
2. Remembering what $\sinh^{-1}(1)$ is equal to.
3. The most simplistic multiplication/division, since *that always seems to trip me up for some reason*.

Comment: If $z=e^{ix},$ it is $z^2+2z-1=0,$ not $z^2-2z+1=0.$ So this gives $z=-1\pm\sqrt2.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That's what I did to achieve the correct solution, it seems that you are currently looking at my second spoiler giving info on an incorrect attempt at solving this. I use $z^2+2z-1=0$ during the correct attempt starting from where everything went wrong the second time.

Comment: Ah, you should not use spoilers for irrelevant information. Leave irrelevant information out of the question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh okay I'll try to remember that

Comment: As it is, this question is very long - much longer than you need it to be. The amount of help you will get here is an inverse relationship with the brevity of your post, except for the needs of showing some work. Showing all your work, including your wrong work, makes it a slog, leading people like me to try to skim your question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The question should be less of a slog now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, we have that $x$ must be complex then by $x=u+iv$

$$\sin(x)=\sin(u+iv)=\sin u \cosh v+i\cos u \sinh v=i$$

which requires

- $\sin u=0 \implies u=2k\pi\;\lor \; u=\pi+2k\pi$

and then

- for $u=2k\pi \implies \cos u=1$ then $\sinh v=1 \implies v=\sinh^{-1}(1)$
- for $u=\pi+2k\pi \implies \cos u=-1$ then $\sinh v=1 \implies v=\sinh^{-1}(-1)$

that is

> $$x=2k\pi +i\sinh^{-1}(1)\;\lor \; x=\pi+2k\pi +i\sinh^{-1}(-1)$$

which corresponds to your solution.